# openstack-install stuck after aborted install

Tags: juju, maas, cloud

I started running `openstack-install` with a maas server.  It told me that none of my servers had wake on lan or ipmi configured and left me hanging.  I broke out of it and now can't get it to `openstck-install -u` (uninstall) correctly.  It says that there is a partial install that needs to be uninstalled.  I have moved the .`juju` directory, removed the .cloud-install directory, removed the `.maasclidb`.  I have killed a twisted process.  Openstack-intall still claims that I have a previous installation.  How to I finish cleaning up the old one so I can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue... unfortunately it was quicker for me to rebuild than to troubleshoot, so no help there. I did find though that if you press "q" to exit this issue does not occur. If you hit "cancel" though this problem pops up again.

Answer (score 1):

The developers are working on a proper fix for this, but they gave me a work around that does the job.  The workaround looks like:

```
mkdir ~/.cloud-install
touch ~/.cloud-install/multi
openstack-install -u
```

Comment: Note that you can also accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are running the latest version of the cloud installer from this PPA?

```
ppa:cloud-installer/testing
```

If `-u` from that PPA doesn't work, let's debug it and file a bug.

Comment: I am running the latest version of cloud installer from ppa:cloud-installer/testing.  the -u option returns that it can't find what type if installation to uninstall.  If I try to tell it what type it can't find any installation.

Comment: Where do I go to file a bug report for openstack-intaller where it will be seen by the right people?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-installer

Answer (score -1):

pls try remove `~/.cloud-install` and then install again (without `-u`)